# Can an AppExchange app install Certificates in a Salesforce instance?

Tags: appexchange, certificates

I want to create an AppExchange app, which needs to install a certificate in Salesforce, so that certificate can be used to make calls with an external server.

Is this possible? If so, could you provide some links where I can find how to do that? I tried looking but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't find it because it is not possible. Even if you could, that would still require additional maintenance because certificates expire. You would need to provide directions for installing/updating certificates to your clients, or provide an alternative delivery mechanism somehow.